# resignFirstResponder does not dismiss the keyboard inside UITableViewCell Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uitextfield

I am working on a `UITableView` using custom `UITableViewCell` class. In each table cell, I have added a `UITextfield`. In the table view, I have set the `addTarget` for all textfields (presenting the `UIViewController` like `BottomSheet` to select options on the `editingDidBegin` action) except the last cell (presenting keyboard to enter any value like any name or so).

**Problem:** My problem is when I am selecting the `UITextfield` to enter any input and without enter return key on keyboard, if I click on other textfield cells to present ViewController, then my keyboard is not getting dismiss. I have tried below solutions but not working:

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag

self.tableView.endEditing(true)

self.view.endEditing(true)
```

**Here is my code:**

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewInspectionTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! NewInspectionTableViewCell
    
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    
    cell.tfForumTitle.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.tfForumTitle.placeholder = self.defaultForums[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageOption.image = self.defaultForumsImages[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.tfForumTitle.delegate = self
    
    if indexPath.row != defaultForums.count - 1 {
        
        cell.tfForumTitle.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onSelectForum), for: UIControl.Event.editingDidBegin)
        
        self.tblNewInspection.endEditing(true)
    }
    else{
        cell.tfForumTitle.text = nameOfOfficial
    }
    
    switch indexPath.row {
    
    case 0: cell.tfForumTitle.text = selectedCCI
    case 1: cell.tfForumTitle.text = selectedCalendarYear
    case 2: cell.tfForumTitle.text = selectedQuarter
    case 3: cell.tfForumTitle.text = selectedDateOfVisit
    case 4: cell.tfForumTitle.text = selectedTimeOfVisit
        
    default:
        break
    }
    
    return cell
    
}


@objc func onSelectForum(textField: UITextField){
    
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
        
        switch textField.tag {
        
        case 0: self.onSelectCCI()
        case 1: self.onSelectCalendarYear()
        case 2: self.onSelectQuarter()
        case 3: self.onSelectDateofVisit()
        case 4: self.onSelectTimeofVisit()
            
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}


func onSelectCalendarYear(){
        
        let nextVC = Constant.HomeStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectOptionViewController") as! SelectOptionViewController
        
        nextVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        nextVC.delegate = self
        nextVC.isSelectionType = "calendar"
        
        self.present(nextVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }


extension NewInspectionVC: UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
            return range.location < 26
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        nameOfOfficial = textField.text ?? ""
        nameOfOfficial = nameOfOfficial.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
        
        //reload table
        tblNewInspection.reloadData()
        
        return true
    }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest me. Thanks!

Comment: are you try with `tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive`

Comment: Yes @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: According to your problem description, you are tapping on another textfield which will open the keyboard indeed, you can't hide a keyboard focusing on a textfield by moving to another textfield which is expecting an entry, try tapping on a cell without a textfield and see if the keyboard dismisses.